# Terminology No-SQL Database

Tags: nosql, terminology

I'm looking for a good explanation of terminology for No-SQL.
I have some colleagues that won't get the point, and for the sake of advancing i need to have definitions of the names.. Though this seems real hard to find.

let's see a Database is a database, talking about No-SQL or SQL it keeps the same name. People do understand that.. But if you start looking on the internet.. there are people that say that you have: "a database with documents", "a database with rows and each row is a document" and "a document has rows",  It's real confusing if you ask me..

So could anybody give a good explanation of the terminology that exists in No-SQL, to improve communication about the subject. And also how this compares to the traditional SQL terminology?(like a row is a document? a table.. etc..)

**EDIT**
Can anybody confirm that this is the relation between the terms:
A Database has multiple documents. 
In this case each documents will be the same as a row and the specification of an Table like in SQL does not exist. you could see all the tables with the same type as a table, if i'm right....?

**EDIT 2**

I'm specifically looking for couchDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/

check out full documentation. everything is perfectly explained.

Comment: Sorry, Maby i should have defined that i'm looking for CouchDB references.. I thought that it would be all the same for no-sql but in Couchdb never seen or heard of an collection... like your reference says.

Comment: I accept your answer together with this reference that explains that every "SQL table" is a type within a Cloudant - couchdb document to make the reference: https://cloudant.com/blog/sql-cloudant-and-going-schemaless/

Comment: couchDB and mongoBD are pretty similar as far as I know. check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437790/when-to-use-couchdb-over-mongodb-and-vice-versa and this http://blog.nahurst.com/visual-guide-to-nosql-systems hope it's helpful

Comment: I wouldn't say that mongoDB and CouchDB are so similar. But that's another topic that doesn't belong here. Through this reference: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/design.html i would say that a collection in Couchdb is an design document which reference to a set of typed documents.. Though you can't say it as a table nor an collection.